# webpack command to trigger build

Tags: angular, webpack

I am working on a angular project where I am looking out to configure the build command in JenkinsFile. The previous build command we used is node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build (to fire the build from 'angular/cli'); I would want to configure the equivalent webpack command. I tried with `node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack/webpack`; but it never worked, Can someone help me with the right command to trigger the webpack through the node_modules directory?

Comment: did you try this command node `node_modules\.bin\webpack `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Answer (score 1):

`node_modules/.bin/` did the trick